# Difference between the pronunciations of ĝo and ĵo

Tags: pronunciation

I saw this sentence in the Duolingo course.

> La infano ŝatas oranĝojn pli on kokaĵon.

The 'ĝo' and 'ĵo' sound exactly same to me.
If they are different pronunciations, how can I pronounce them differently?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, ĝo is pronounced like dĵo would be (but you have almost no word with "dĵ" (if any)). Don't know if my explanation is enough but I think that's the easiest way to put it : ĝ is a ĵ with a d before

Comment: I made a search in Tekstaro, according to which the combination _dĵ_ is mostly found in proper names (like ex-Iranian president _Rafsandĵani_) and as esperantised version of the title disc jockey (e.g _DĴ Kunar_). There are some compound words (e.g. _televidĵurnalo_), but the only word which I found where the combination is within one word is the direct loan word _hadĵio_ from the non-Zamenhof part of _Fundamenta Krestomatio_. Later this has been corrected to the form [_haĝo, haĝulo_](https://vortaro.net/#haĝo_kd). So your guess of "if any" is probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

The letter `Ĝ`/`ĝ` is rendered in IPA (the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)) as `d͡ʒ`.  This is the sound most English speakers make when pronouncing the `g`s in the English word `ginger`, and the `g`s and `j`s in `Gene the giant giraffe gingerly jumps joyfully`.

The letter `Ĵ`/`ĵ` is rendered in IPA as `ʒ`.  This is the sound most English speakers make when pronouncing the final `g`s in the English words `garage` and `mirage` (although you could argue that those words are derived from French).  (Note that the word `garage` has two `g`s; the first is like the Esperanto `g`, the second is like the Esperanto `ĵ`.)

The `s` in the English words `measure`, `pleasure`, and `treasure` also matches the sound of the Esperanto letter `Ĵ`/`ĵ`.  So the Esperanto letter `Ĵ`/`ĵ` makes the same sound a `g` and `s` make in this sentence:  `That treasure ain't no pleasure -- but a mirage!`

---

Note:  I'm not an expert in IPA, so if I got the rendering(s) wrong, please correct me.

Comment: _garage_ might be a confusing example because in some accents it is pronounced to rhyme with _ridge_.

Comment: Your IPA is fine. /ʒ/ is indeed a marginal phoneme in English, and it does exist; I'd suggest to use words like "Zhukov" to illustrate it (since the phoneme does exist, native speakers have no problems with the word and it is unambiguous, unlike e.g. *garage*). What **is** a problem is that in English, affricates are not phonemically different from stop+sibilant clusters. It is better to use a different language to illustrate the point.

Comment: Speaking as someone who has a `ĵ` sound in his name, I can say that, in general, native English speakers are much more likely to correctly pronounce the /ʒ/ in "garage" than in a name like "Zhukov".  Even if regional accents exist where a speaker pronounces "garage" to rhyme with "carriage", they're likely exposed to enough American movies and TV shows that they are familiar with the common English/American pronunciation of "garage", and so shouldn't have much of a problem imitating its /ʒ/ sound.

Answer (score 0):

In the book I learnt from it said that *ĵ* is pronounced like the *s* sound in the word *pleasure* in English.

Perhaps then you could compare the sounds of the English words *pleasure* and *pledger* which only differ by the same sounds as *ĵ* and *ĝ*. (I’m not sure if the word *pledger* really exists but I guess it would be someone who makes a pledge).